# How to retrieve value from Web SQL Database by using function?

Tags: javascript, html, sql, web-sql

I have a textbox with button.
how can i retrieve value from Web SQL database in JS file by using onclick function and display in textbox?

Comment: I only give you hint to use web services and ajax for this purpose,Now you make effort yourself.

Comment: You can also check the jquery get or ajax function for getting data  in js function.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Ajax` for this:

```
XmlHttp.onreadystatechange = HandleUserNameResult;
XmlHttp.open("GET", requestUrl, true);
XmlHttp.send(null);


function HandleUserNameResult() {
     var responseText = XmlHttp.responseText;    //Here you will get the result;
}
```